# Finding the limit of $ \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1}{x^2} \int_0^{(\sin(x))^2} \ln(1+\cos(t))dt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits

I am trying to calculate the limit of

$$ \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1}{x^2} \int_0^{(\sin(x))^2} \ln(1+\cos(t))dt$$

I have no idea which approach is appropriate. Calulating the integral happens to be quite complicated, too complicated to be the right approach I guess. There must be some clever trick. What are your suggestions? Thanks for your help!

Comment: $$\frac{1}{x^2} = \biggl(\frac{\sin (x)}{x}\biggr)^2\cdot \frac{1}{(\sin (x))^2}$$

Comment: $$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(t)\,dt$$ is the _average_ of $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need of De l'Hopital. We have that $g(t)=\log(1+\cos t)$ is a continuous function in a neighbourhood of the origin, and $g(0)=\log 2$. By the mean value theorem:
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}\int_{0}^{\sin^2 x}\log(1+\cos t)\,dt = g(0)=\log 2$$
and it is well-known that:
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2 = 1.$$

Comment: This is the good argument here, simple and direct.

Answer (score 3):

Why not to use the fundamental theorem of calculus and L'Hospital rule ?

Consider $$u= \int_0^{a[x]} f(t)\,dt$$ $$v= \frac{1}{x^2}$$ So, from the fundamental theorem of calculus $$u'=f\big(a(x)\big)\, a'(x)$$ and $v'=2x$. Now, by differentiation $$u''=f\big(a(x)\big)\, a''(x)+a'(x)^2\, f'\big(a(x)\big)$$ and $v''=2$. So, consider $\frac{u''}{v''}$.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: Use L'hospitale rule. Can you use the Chain Rule with the hint in the comment?